# Find & Replace string in XML using Linq

Tags: .net, xml, linq

Is it possible to search for a given string in an XML file, then replace it's value with something else using linq and without specifying any element's by name? Would it be easier to just load the XML file as a giant string and start replacing the old fashioned way?

XML Template:

```
<root>
 <level1/>
 <level1>@variable@</level1>
 <level1/>
</root>
```

I'll basically want to turn the "@variable@" into something like "ThisValue"

Comment: Just in text nodes, or also in attributes etc?

Comment: what is the language you are using?

Comment: could the string could be in both the attribute and text. My language of preference is vb, but anything .net works fine.

Comment: Is there any particular need to use LINQ? Asking `How to do X with Y?` seems like an inferior question to `What's the "best" way to do X?`...

Comment: Nah not really, I know how to change it with regular XPath. But just for my knowledge, as I'm barely beginning to learn about Linq, I wanted to see if it could be done. I've looked around and haven't found an answer to this.